# spring jpa auditing with localdate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to get a monthly list, weekly list according to created date but JPA doesn't support `LocalDate`.
My Code like this:

`UserDao`:

```
List<User> findByCreatedAtBetween(LocalDate start, LocalDate end);
```

`UserEntity`:

```
@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
private LocalDate createdAt;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@LastModifiedDate
private LocalDate updatedAt;
```

But `createdAt` and `updatedAt` only supports `java.util.Date`. Why doesn't it support `java.time.LocalDate`?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @JensSchauder I want to perform operation to use LocalDate

Comment: `LocalDate` doesn't make much sense for timestamps http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/

Answer (score 0):

As you found out `LocalDate` is currently not supported by Spring Data Envers, or actually in Spring Data Commons where the relevant code resides.

The reason for this is that these timestamp fields are intended to, well, be time stamps, i.e. specify points in time. `LocalDate` doesn't do that. The problem is not so much the lack of accuracy, but that `LocalDate` and its sibling `LocalDateTime` do not define an ordering. It is perfectly possible that something that happened on the Jan 1st, 1970 happened after something else that happened on Jan 2nd, 1970. For more detail refer to the JavaDoc or to http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2018/03/14/dont-use-localdatetime/

Note that `LocalDateTime` is supported, but mostly because that was implemented before we did realize that it is the wrong type to use for this purpose.

I highly recommend using `Instant` as the type for this kind of fields.

Comment: any update to this answer? I am trying to implement with `OffsetDateTime` which supports  (potentially) relevant timezones. However, the error message says that even `Instant` is not supported.

Comment: Could you create a separate question for this?